# How to refresh page with a href in Firefox

Tags: javascript, refresh

I am using the following code to refresh my page using a link:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(0)">
```

This works in Safari (i.e. the page is refreshed to the new content).  In Firefox however I am getting the cached page.  Is there a way of adapting this to work in all browsers, or do I need a different method?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use:

```
<a href='#' onclick='location.reload(true); return false;'>click me</a>
```

Comment: The below answer is simpler.

Answer (score 6):

You can just leave the href as empty and it will reload the current page.

```
<a href=''>Reload</a>
```

No need for onclick event or #.